# How set cookie with go?

Tags: go, cookies, goland

I would like my golang server to send back a cookie in HTTP raiponce that will be placed on the user's computer.
Here is my code

```
func userLogin(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        cookie := &http.Cookie{
            Name:  "my-cookie",
            Value: "some value",
        }
        http.SetCookie(w, cookie)
        w.WriteHeader(200)
        w.Write([]byte("cookie is set))
        return
}
```

it is marked in the header

[image]

but I see no cookie to create

[image]

Comment: Note that cookie values must not contain spaces.

Comment: yes it just for the demonstation

Comment: You are looking for cookies at http://localhost:3000.  Is that where your Go server is running?   The response headers displayed in the image are not the headers created by `userLogin`.  Is there more code that you are not showing us?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The browser defaults the cookie path to the request path.

It looks like you are setting the cookie in a request to `/<something here>`, but are expecting the cookie in a request to `/`.

Fix by setting the cookie path to `/`.

```
func userLogin(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        cookie := &http.Cookie{
            Name:  "my-cookie",
            Value: "some value",
            Path: "/",
        }
        http.SetCookie(w, cookie)
        w.WriteHeader(200)
        w.Write([]byte("cookie is set))
}
```

Comment: I added the / but it didn't change anything